# Visual Studio 2015 Обращение к пространству имен

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Не могу получить доступ к элементам пространства System.Web

Скрин из Object Browser

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Много чего есть, а при обращении в коде доступны 3 элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже using не помогает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Библиотека System.Web.dll к проекту подключена? Судя по признакам - нет.

Comment: Точно, однако заметил, что mscorlib тоже не подключена, а в проекте using System.Collections.Generic есть и доступны классы обобщенных коллекций, как так?

Comment: А вы попробуйте подключить mscorlib и сами увидете ответ на свой вопрос ;)

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Классы их одного пространства имен могут быть определены в разных сборках (разных DLL).

`System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission` и остальные два класса из допечатки [определены в System.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspnethostingpermission(v=vs.110).aspx), которая подключена к проекту по умолчанию.

Остальные классы из `System.Web` определены в `System.Web.dll`, которую нужно добаить в References проекта - выбрать проект в Solution Explorer, кликнуть правой кнопкой по References, Add Reference.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mail; // к примеру
```

Либо если вам известено, что вам нужно, то напишите его, а студия сама предложит что надо добавить в using.